# memory leak? xampp cannot run PHP processes

Tags: php, xampp

I'd been developing a php+mysql+simpleDOM script overnight under local environment (using xampp), well, my xampp seems to be not able to handle more file_get_contents() commands, and other DOM related functions.

Always giving error something like:

```
file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Not enough storage is available to process this command
```

funny because this is PHP, so no memory leaks right?

My php.ini memory limit is already set to 512M. Anything I should know?

The function seems to be working at first, then after 3rd run, it gives me that error. anything i need to do to free up that memory?

===================================
to answer the comments:

here is the function I am using:

```
<?php
function get_country($domain) {
$ip = gethostbyname($domain);
$details =  json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}"));
return $details->country;
}

echo get_country("stackoverflow.com"); // -> "US"
echo get_country("bbc.co.uk"); // -> "GB"
?>
```

==================================

Windows 7, 64-bit Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you provided the code that was actually utilizing `file_get_contents`.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: btw, I already tried restarting the xampp services. no luck, now I'm stucked developing.

Comment: @user1824371 It's not php, something is wrong inside getaddrinfo: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/106167

Comment: no luck, done everything in the article. my 64-bit OS sucks.